# Segmentation fault with fscanf on large files

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am attempting to store the first two numbers in a file as variables, then the remaining numbers in a file in an array.

The following code works fine on smaller inputs, but I am wondering - why does it error on larger input files? I am able to print out all the values in the for loop, before getting Segmentation Fault: 11 returned.

```
FILE * fp;

fp = fopen("test.text", "r");

int i;
fscanf(fp, "%d", &i);
int param1 = i;
fscanf(fp, "%d", &i);
int param2 = i;

int list[param2];
int j;

for (j = 0; j < param2; j++) {
  fscanf(fp, "%d", &list[j]);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Maybe that's because `param2` is too big, so `int list[param2];` can't be allocated

Comment: @ForceBru `d` is at most 2^14.

Answer (score 2):

As @ForceBru already briefly commented, it's the issue with `int list[param2];`

When a list is declared like this, the buffer is stored on stack, the allocation happens simply by the compiler increasing the stack pointer by param2 amount.

If this  is compiled with the j allocated after the buffer, which might be the case here, the computer will access the location `stack_pointer + param2 * sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)` to store 0 (j = 0).

The stack is limited, hence the name of this site, when a buffer so far outside the stack gets accessed, the kernel will just see you write somewhere very far away from any legitimate memory and it will assume something went wrong.

For large buffers, take a look at malloc.